# "invalid Object name" for some Users

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

we wanted to move parts of our Database to a new Server, after exporting the data, Users etc only I and one other person, who probably has a admin role as well, are able to connect to the new Server.
Everybody else gets "Invalid Object name ..." for the first Table that should be queried.
(tablename: [Maintenance]).
The Guy how created our new Database, whom I contacted for support, tried to connect with the MS SQL Serverconsole to the DB and was able to watch views and tables.
The users of our program are identified by the DB over there windows login, and the DB guy added a private user to the group, where my tester also belong to.
This user was used for the test.
For connection to DB the following connectionstring is used:

```
Data Source=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;
Initial Catalog=Prime;Data Source=#SERVERADDRESS#;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=2;Max Pool Size=6;enlist=True
```

And then for accessing the DB a `system.data.sqlclient.SqlConnection` is used. The program it self is written in vb.net, therefore the tag^^

What I tryed so far myself is the following:

```
GRANT SELECT on PrimeDB to [public]
```

result: `Cannot find the object 'PrimeDB', because it does not exist or you do not have permission` ,PrimeDB is the schema name.

Before I tried to use the guest user to access the DB, after I granted him the nessesary permissions on our DB to read/write/edit tables. But in the end the DB again failed to do so, telling me "Login failed for user guest", and yes I set the activated the guest-user.
I did this like this:

> ```
> Data Source=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User Id=guest;
> Initial Catalog=Prime;Data Source=#SERVERADDRESS#;
> MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=2;Max Pool Size=6;enlist=True
> ```

What could be the problem? For me it sounds like its some Permission problem, but the Serverowner said everything is ok

Comment: It definitely sounds like a permission problem.  You and another admin user have access to the database objects, while other users do not.  (This is one reason why I always recommend using a service account for application access instead of individual accounts.  It's easier to manage one user than many.)  And the guest login clearly failed.  Maybe there needs to be a password with it as well?

Comment: but what would that password be? the guestuser was predifined but not activ